# Convert Hadamard product to Matrix product (simplified)

Tags: matrices, inner-products, hadamard-product

So I have a matrix $Z \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times d}$ (which has repeated row vectors of size m) and $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times d}$ and I use hadamard product for them $Z \circ A$.
My goal is to somehow separate Z and A in a way A will stay in the right hand side of the brackets i.e. either $$Z \circ A = (Z\cdot X)A$$ or $$Z \circ A = (Z\circ X)A$$ .

Is there any way I can do this?

Answer (score -1):

Matrix A is already on the right-hand side. I am not sure there is any operator between **)** and matrix **A** on the right side in your question.

However, If exists $Z^T$ then, you could have $(Z*Z^T) * A$.